# How can I fix JSON format string with PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

Here is what I did.

I get the localStorage from javascript and JSON.stringify it.

```
document.getElementById("data").value = JSON.stringify(window.localStorage);
```

Then I sent this data to PHP and save it to MYSQL using json_encode.
**I removed the json_encode according to the comments.**

```
$data = $_POST["data"];
//Save to database
```

When I try to get the data back from the database, it is corrupt like below and I cannot parse using javascript or php.

```
"{"UserData10-1":"{\"Ydosiaas\":\"NA\",\"Mpdioasp\":\"NA\"}","UserData1011-1":"{\"Mpdioasp\":\"NA\",\"Ydosiaas\":\"NA\"}","UserData1011-1":"{\"Pdsaousa\":\"NA\",\"Ydosiaas\":\"NA\"}"
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

One thing I figure out is, when I try to parse the JSON at the first place before I save it to database, it is working. 
But parsing got error when I try to get it back again from the database. 
Now the code become like the following. But Still cannot parse :(

```
 {"UserData882-1":""{\"Ydosiaas\":\"NA\",\"Mpdioasp\":\"Normal, position\"}"","UserData7-2":""{\"Mpdioasp\":\"NA\",\"Ydosiaas\":\"Normal, eq\"}"","UserData7-2":""{\"Tweqas\":\"NA\",\"Ydosiaas\":\"Normal, equ\"}""}
```

Comment: It's not corrupted, It's a valid JSON string with escaped special characters with `\ `.

Comment: But when I parse it show an error "Unexpected token U in JSON at position 3
  Object.parse (native)()";

Comment: The error is the quotes. Internal quotes need to be different to the quotes that surround the stirng. E.g `'{"UserData10-1" : "..."}'`. It  also appears you are converting to JSON twicel; once with javascript then with php which could be causing this issue.

Comment: I removed it now. But still now luck. :(

Comment: I  think we need to see how you are setting local storage as the `"` are still not what I would expect and are would be causing parse errors. Please consider creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It looks like you may be trying to again convert data that is already JSON to JSON.

Comment: Thanks @JonP. As you pointed out, I replace the internal quotes from PHP and it is fine now. Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

use

JSON.stringify( window.localStorage.getItem('key'))

Comment: Okay. You mean I have to stringify the item. But I also need keys and all the items.

Comment: you handled json encoding using JSON.stringify.
$data = json_encode($_POST["data"]); is not necessary

Comment: I removed it. But I still cannot parse.

Answer (score 0):

if your data is stored as a valid json object in the local storage then use JSON.stringify(data) before sending it to the PHP backend.

If you are return data as json and there are other entities which you are returning as response then you should json_decode the data and combine it with rest of the response and then again json_encode it so that you response it consistent.

Also you could use `json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);` to prevent inserting multiple slashes